# Polynomial String - Identify Constants

Tags: java, string, polynomials

While reading a polynomial like "25x^2 + 12x^-10 - 3 - 73x^8", I want to locate the constant ("3" in this case) and manipulate it by appending "x^0". I have a fair idea of how to go about appending it, but unsure how to actually identify a constant substring within the polynomial.

One possible way is to manually add if statements with `str.contains("3+")` / `str.contains("3-")`. However, this is just hardcoding the solution.

So, I was wondering if there is some sort of in-built method or a regex that can be used. I was thinking along the lines of `str.contains("{1-999}+")` and `str.contains("{1-999}-")` which recognizes there is an integer of the specified range, followed by a + or - sign.

This is kind of what I am looking for:

```
if(poly.contains("{1-999}+")) {
     poly = poly.replace("x+", "x^0+");
} 
if(poly.contains("{1-999}-")) {
     poly = poly.replace("x+", "x^0-");
}
```

Comment: Your idea of looking for a number followed by a + or - isn't going to work, because for example in "25x^2 + ..." you also have a number 2 followed by a + sign, which would match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace all consecutive digits with a space before and after (unless they are at the beginning or end of the string).

```
String str = "25x^2 + 12x^-10 - 3 - 73x^8";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<=^| )\\d+(?= |$)", "$0x^0"));
```

Comment: While I was testing it, i found that its not working when constants are the first term. Like for "-3 + 25x^2 + 12x^-10 - 73x^8". Is there a way to modify the regex to accommodate this case?

Comment: @Rahul You can change it to `str.replaceAll("(?<=^| )-?\\d+(?= |$)", "$0x^0")` to accommodate for an optional negative sign.